# Is it possible to manipulate camera data before sending in WebRTC?

Tags: android, webrtc

We are trying to use filters (for example black&white, sepia), masks or something like that on video frames in WebRTC. But we are trying to do this before sending the data (I mean camera frames). Of course, we can change the frames on the receiver side but we want to do it on the sender side? Is it possible to manipulate data, etc. VideoFrames in call before sending?

Answer (score 2):

No and yes. 
**No**, there is no native WebRTC method for this. The manipulation of added MediaStreams in WebRTC offers only [applyConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints) and [Transceiver-sendEncodings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpEncodingParameters), both can be used to manipulate framerate or video dimensions, but they do not do what you want. 
**Yes**, but you have to use the HTML5 Canvas API in combination with WebRTC. If you want to apply a black and white filter, here is a bit of code on how you can do it, you can just copy into a .html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>grayscale example</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="demo" autoplay></video>
<script>
    // I shamelessly copied this from https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html
    function grayScaleCanvas(canvas, context){
        const width = canvas.width;
        const height = canvas.height;
        const frame=context.getImageData(0,0, width, height);
        // This loop gets every pixels on the image and puts the rgb average as value
        for (let i=0; i<height; i++){
            for (let j=0; j<width; j++){
                const index=(i*4)*frame.width+(j*4);
                const red=frame.data[index];
                const green=frame.data[index+1];
                const blue=frame.data[index+2];
                const average=(red+green+blue)/3;
                frame.data[index]=average;
                frame.data[index+1]=average;
                frame.data[index+2]=average;
            }
        }
        context.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
    }

    // 1. paint the getUserMedia-Stream on a canvas,
    // 2. manipulate the canvas to create the grayscale-effect,
    // 3.return a canvas capture stream with the given framerate
    function streamToGrayScaledVersion(stream, fps=30, width=640, height=480){
        const video = document.createElement('video');
        video.autoplay = true;
        video.srcObject = stream;
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const toCanvas = function(){
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
            grayScaleCanvas(canvas, context);
            requestAnimationFrame(toCanvas);
        };
        requestAnimationFrame(toCanvas);
        return canvas.captureStream(fps);
    }

    const demoVideo = document.getElementById("demo");
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
        .then(streamToGrayScaledVersion)
        .then(stream => demo.srcObject = stream)
        .catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(My apologies for the incovenience, I already tried creating a "real" StackOverflow snippet for this, but something like a security origin error popped up, possibly diallowing getUserMedia in snippets)

Answer (score 0):

I use the latest build for Android WebRTC `google-webrtc-1.0.32006` and there is no direct possibility in SDK for this but it could be solved with the `Decorator` design pattern. You have to create your own decorator for the `CapturerObserver` and do what you what with `VideoFrame` before sending.

```
class CapturerObserverDecorator(private val capturerObserver: CapturerObserver?) : CapturerObserver {

    override fun onCapturerStarted(success: Boolean) {
        capturerObserver?.onCapturerStarted(success)
    }

    override fun onCapturerStopped() {
        capturerObserver?.onCapturerStopped()
    }

    override fun onFrameCaptured(videoFrame: VideoFrame) {
        // TODO: Do your manipulations with VideoFrame here and pass result videoFrame
        capturerObserver?.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame)
    }
}
```